# How can I remember Starcraft 2 counters?

Tags: starcraft-2

The military units in SC2 almost all have counters (i.e. Thor counters Siege Tank). There are a lot of military units, so it makes it hard to remember all the counters. Is there an easy way to remember what counters what?

Comment: Look at the abilities/attacks description and think:)

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy way to learn about a game and all it's little things like this aside from playing it a lot or doing research. Learning things like zealots counters zerglings and roaches counter zealots. Or that concussion shells is a must against most protoss units is something you learn as you play.

Comment: @Sorean So, we can learn all these only thruogh practise, right?

Comment: There aren't exactly hard counters in Starcraft, but you can get a pretty good guess based on their basic properties. Marauders deal high single-target damage on a moderate cooldown and deal bonus damage to Armoured. This makes them amazing against units like Roaches and Stalkers, but relatively weaker to Zerglings and Hydralisks. Many times relative strength of units is dependent on terrain. Splash damage and range are both much more valuable in a choke than on a plain.

Answer (score 3):

There is no substitute better than practice and research. These two are the best way to learn what units are generally better than others. I will provide you this link to learn about all the units and their abilities as listing everything would create far too large of an answer.

Certain units are always better than another, to use Sconibulus' example, a marauder is great versus a stalker, but does poorly to zerglings.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Units

Watching high level play and tournaments with good commentators will greatly expand your knowledge about gameplay and strategies as well. Again you can find a lot of information on upcoming tournaments from Team Liquid located on the far right of the menu.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

You can only learn through practice, there are so many different situations that you can't just research it. You have to play and experience and discover for yourself what is good against what.

Some things to keep in mind are: Terrain, numbers, unit cost (resources as well as time), tech level of the unit, range, AOE damage, bonuses to x, (and many more)

Asking someone does x beat y, is not a good way to learn because of all these different scenarios. However if you have a replay which demonstrates the situation it's good to show it to someone and then maybe someone more experienced can help you understand what would've been a better counter in that case.

In order to learn yourself what counters what, you just have to try. Play games and lose, work out why you lost, was it because your units were countered by the enemy? If so what do you think would've been better? Next time you encounter the same situation try those units instead and see if it works.

We learn the most from losing, look through the replays of your losses to better understand what counters what and when it does (and doesnt).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Starcraft 2 official page
Where you can find unit detail infomation, strong against, weak against.

For example, [zergling](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/zergling) which strong against marauder, hydralist, Stalker and weak against hellion, colossus, baneling